# Why jest.fn is not called

Tags: jestjs

I am using ES5 with Jest. Why the test below fails?

service.js

```
function add(a, b) {
  return generateToken(a,b);
}

function generateToken(a,b) {
  return a+b;
}

module.exports = {
  add,
  generateToken
};
```

service-test.js

```
var service = require ('./service');

describe('service', () => {
  it('generateToken should be called', () => {
    service.generateToken = jest.fn();
    serivce.add(1,2);
    expect(service.generateToken).toBeCalled();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
function add(a, b) {
  return generateToken(a,b);
}
```

to

```
function add(a, b) {
  return module.exports.generateToken(a,b);
}
```